# Removing current view and adding another using segmented controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use segmented controller to swap my `viewsControllers`. But the problem is, I do not know the best logic to do so. Currently I am doing as following, which actually is causing memory leaks and do not remove views correctly.

I update my view if clicked on segmented index( inViewDidLoad the selected index is 1) Yes I know this is not logical at all what I am doing but that is why I need your help:

```
private func updateView() {
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            add(asChildViewController: difficulty2ViewController)
        }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
            add(asChildViewController: difficulty3ViewController)
        }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
            add(asChildViewController: difficulty4ViewController)
        }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 3{
            add(asChildViewController: difficulty5ViewController)
        }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 4{
            add(asChildViewController: difficulty6ViewController)
        }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 5{
            add(asChildViewController: difficulty7ViewController)
        }
    }
```

Like this I add the view:

```
private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Add Child View Controller
        addChildViewController(viewController)

        // Add Child View as Subview
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)

        //Little animation
        viewController.view.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            viewController.view.alpha = 1.0
        }

        // Configure Child View
        viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

And like that I remove the view:

```
private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

        // Remove Child View From Superview
        viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
```

My question is, how I can remove current view and then add new view? Or is there better solution?

Comment: Well, let's try and clarify... Where is the UISegmentedControl, and the updateView(), add() and remove() funcs? I'm assuming you have a "main" view controller with the funcs, and its view contains the UISegmentedControl... and you add / remove as "subs" of that main VC and view? If so, then you should have no trouble with remove() + add() process, unless it is the *current* child.

Comment: I have MasterViewController, which contains all the logic and controls the flow. After that I have all the other viewControllers.

Comment: Utilise `switch cases` over `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex`.
You can evaluate `typedef`ing an `enum` declaration for each segment, will improve *sanity* & code *legibility*.

Comment: @ystack add it as answer. Enums saved my life today.

Comment: woah! glad that this bit helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilise `switch cases` over `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex`.
You can evaluate `typedef`ing an `enum` declaration for each segment, will improve *sanity* & code *legibility*.